# Reference for book -- cultural relativism -- cognised/cognisable/real worlds (with golden dragon)

Tags: reference-request, relativism

I am hoping someone can give me a reference for a book I read once.  (I should [as in "would"] have a note, but if I do I can not find it.)

The book was, from memory, a collection of articles/contributions.  The article in which I am interested was an argument against cultural relativism.  I think the book was arguments for and against on this topic.  (Possibly, the next or previous article talked about a boat on a river.)

The article in question was (easily) the best I have read, against cultural relativism.

I remember two features in the article.
• There was an interesting story; the author [I think it was] was in a foreign country [it felt like Africa], and there was a local who was going to show him/her a golden dragon.  There was no question in the mind of the local that there definitely was one.  In the end, the author never got to see the (putative) golden dragon.  (Sorry about the spoiler!)
• The viewpoint or categorisation that the article took (that made the argument good) was to represent the {cultural relativism} view as being... that we live in different   • cognisable,  • cognised or • real  worlds.

Thank you in advance!

[I think there should be a tag "cultural relativism".]

Comment: https://is.muni.cz/el/1423/jaro2017/SAN103/um/Geertz_Anti_Anti_Relativism.pdf Distinguished Lecture: Anti Anti-Relativism
Clifford Geertz
American Anthropologist, New Series, Vol. 86, No. 2. (Jun., 1984), pp. 263-278. Search for "dragon" finds 6 references in this paper. It sounds like what you have described here.